# HTML+CSS to RTF (in PHP)?

Tags: php, html, css, rtf

I am seeking a solution to converting HTML + CSS (2.1) to RTF in PHP.  While I have found a superb solution for HTML to PDF in [Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com), I've yet to find anything that:

- can convert HTML to RTF (or DOC);
- runs on a Linux server;
- is callable from PHP;
- handles paged media and the ability to add page headers and footers; and
- handles tables.

Is there anything out there?

Comment: If only it wasn't $4000~ for a server license!

Comment: Mind sharing what you ended up using?

Comment: @meder I never really found a good solution for this. In the end the requirement went away so it became a non-issue.

Comment: html2pdf was a good library for html to pdf conversion. I am looking for same for htmlToDoc /DOCx/ rtf???

Comment: Haven't looked through thoroughly, but http://w3.org/Tools/html2things.html may be of interest

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to do this is using **phpLiveDocx**. It is component for the Zend Framework and completely free.

Supported template file formats (input)

- DOCX - Microsoft Word DOCX Format
- DOC - Microsoft Word DOC Format
- RTF - Rich Text Format File
- TXD - TX Text Control Format

Supported document file formats (output)

- DOCX - Microsoft Word DOCX Format
- DOC - Microsoft Word DOC Format
- RTF - Rich Text Format File
- PDF - Acrobat Portable Document Format
- TXD - TX Text Control Format
- TXT - ANSI Plain Text

From the project web site:

"phpLiveDocx allows developers to generate documents by combining structured data from PHP with a template, created in a word processor. The resulting document can be saved as a PDF, DOCX, DOC or RTF file. The concept is the same as with mail-merge."

For details, see:

http://www.phplivedocx.org/articles/brief-introduction-to-phplivedocx/

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but liveDocX doesn't support HTML as input. Is this correct?

Answer (score 12):

**For all your document conversion needs**, you can use [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/) (running in headless mode.)  You may invoke it [with command-line parameters](http://club.mandriva.com/xwiki/bin/KB/OpenOfficeCommandline) to perform conversion, or you may [interface with it](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/) using [PUNO](http://puno.sourceforge.net/install.html). You may spawn a new OpenOffice instance everytime you need conversion, or you may have one ore more instances run as daemon(s).

With either interfacing choice, you will probably want to use a macro to add custom headers and footers after opening the html, but before exporting as Word.

Answer (score 1):

There is a PHP wrapper for HTML-to-PDF converter [PD4ML](http://pd4ml.com/php.htm). Optionally PD4ML can produce [RTF instead of PDF](http://pd4ml.com/cookbook/html_to_rtf_conversion.htm). You just only need to add **-outformat rtf** or **-outformat rtfwmf** to its command line (and adjust HTTP header correspondingly).