# count words from doc and docx file

Tags: php, ms-word, word-count

I want to count number of words from **.doc** and **.docx** file.

I have tried below code:-

```
$file_upload = 'test.docx';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$file_content = " ";
if ($zip -> open($file_upload) === true)
{
   if ( ($index = $zip -> locateName("word/document.xml")) !== false ) 
   {
                $data = $zip -> getFromIndex($index);
                $xml->formatOutput = true;
                $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);

                $file_content = strip_tags($xml -> saveXML());
    }


   echo str_word_count($file_content);
}
```

But the above code is not giving me the expected result.

I also searched google and also stackoverflow search section. But I didn't found my desired answer.

**NOTE:- The code will not be operating system or server dependent.**

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330660/count-number-of-words-from-doc-txt-docx-files

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari I have already tried that one. But not get my desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Take a look to [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com/).

(source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052292/php-read-and-write-in-ms-word))