# PHP - Get a word count from an uploaded Microsoft Word document

Tags: php, upload, ms-word, .doc

I am trying to grab a word count from an uploaded word doc `(.doc, .docx, .rtf)` but it always carries through the annoying Word formatting.

Anybody tackled this issue before and know how to solve it?
Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330660/count-number-of-words-from-doc-txt-docx-files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to:

1. Distinguish the file type

   ```
   $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   $file_extn = end(explode(".", strtolower($_FILES['image']['name'])));

   if($file_extn == "doc" || $file_extn == "docx"){
       docx2text();
   }elseif($file_extn == "rtf"){
       rtf2text();
   }
   ```
2. Convert the document to text

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/7371315/2512934 for doc or docx
   http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_the_clean_text_from_rtf.php for rtf
3. Count the words
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) This work perfectly for .docx but unfortunately doesn't for .rtf.
Don't suppose you could help me with that too? :)

Comment: I've edited the answer. If I have answered your question, please mark mine as the answer to the question.