# Get word count for first line in doc/docx/pdf file in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, docx

I need to upload files count words and letters of .docx, .doc, and .pdf extensions. I try with help of [DOCUNTER](https://github.com/joeblurton/doccounter) but it is not working for me. link: https://github.com/joeblurton/doccounter.

```
include "class.doccounter.php";

$doc = new DocCounter();
$doc->setFile("sample.pdf");

print_r($doc->getInfo());
echo $doc->getInfo()->wordCount;
```

**The result is not found by this code in PHP**

Comment: That library you tried to use there is marked as “obsolete” by the developer itself, and it says right there on the github page, _“Users found too much variance in the output with different save files. I recommend using the LibreOffice cli tools to achieve the same ends.”_ - so look into that, maybe.

Comment: I need in PHP so I think it is in java and c++

Comment: Then you will have to go and find yourself something in PHP, that actually works. Asking for recommendations on libraries is explicitly considered off-topic here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967828/php-get-a-word-count-from-an-uploaded-microsoft-word-document

Comment: I have already tried with but not working with PDF wordcount and .doc wordcount