# Word to xml conversion

Tags: php, xml, xslt, ms-word

Here is my problem: My organization wants to upload word documents from users to the server. On the server side, the word document (enforced with styles) needs to be converted to XML format files. Next, I need to use php to parse the open xml formats files and put the content into the database. Does anyone know how to convert word to XML on server side automatically?Is there any API or sample codes for php to parse Open XML Formats? Your suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Newer versions of Word (.docx) and OpenOffice's .odt format already *are* XML. Rename one of them to .zip and take a look

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052292/php-read-and-write-in-ms-word

Comment: Thanks @Pekka웃 i tried the save *.xml as option but its generating lot of xml code for a simple word document, which includes all fonts and other properties of the word.

Comment: No, I mean the native docx format is a ZIP file which contains XML data. You might be able to extract your data from there.

Comment: This is ok but we have to rename the file manually. is there any automated process.. the actual requirement is explained in question. User will upload doc files to server. the server script has to convert it to xml format and xml file will be parsed as per the xsd schema...

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using [VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ff688774.aspx)?

I have had to do similar work and I've used VBA within a WSF or VBS file. If you're server is a Windows environment it will run right from the OS. You can execute this from PHP (not recommended) or drop the Docx file into a hot folder outside of the web server environment. I recommend the latter since the web server env. can introduce security issues.

Another note, if you want to separate content from styling, you're going to need to perform some post-processing on the output markup. Word is a "word" processor so styling is what it is designed to do. If this is a requirement, I would suggest moving to a structured, XML-based authoring tool instead.

Hope this helps!