# simple rtf file in php

Tags: php, html, ms-word, rtf

Can anyone help me to create simple .rtf file using php? For example: I have a page:

```
<table>
<tr><td>ID</td><tr><td>sth</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><tr><td>sth1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><tr><td>sth1</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><tr><td>sth1</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to create a .rtf file with this table to let user to edit it using program like MS Word. I was trying with this: http://books.msspace.net/mirrorbooks/php5/067232511X/ch28lev1sec1.html but it did not help me.

Comment: Maybe useful: [stackoverflow: HTML+CSS to RTF (in PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605936/htmlcss-to-rtf-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

// $rtf holds your complete file data

// save file on your server 1st

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/outfile.rtf', $rtf);
```

// then offer it as download

```
header("Content-type: application/rtf");
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/outfile.rtf");
exit();
```

Comment: U didn't understand me. For example: how to make text bold? Sth like: 
$rtf = "<b>bold</b>"; don't work here

Comment: Now i get it. will look into it. Check this out: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/11/3/0 @user3085804